# PL/SQL code to load data from flat file with varying column sequence into oracle table

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-columns

I need ideas or PL/SQL code to load data from flat file with varying column sequence into oracle table.

e.g. 
Day 1, file will contain data

```
Col1,Col2,Col3

ID,Name,Address

10,ABC,NY

20,XYZ,SC
```

Day 2, file will contain data

```
Col1,Col2,Col3

Name,ID,Address

LMN,30,NY

OPQ,40,WD
```

And I want to load it into a oracle table like below

```
ID,Name,Address

10,ABC,NY

20,XYZ,SC

30,LMN,NY

40,OPQ,WD
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can start [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9535214200346030268) and refine your question afterwards.

Comment: Sit together and have a word with the people/entity who send you the file and agree upon a standard format. Yes, we can write some dynamic code. But, In my opinion  it's wasting your resources  to handle such data which can also cause potential issues, rather than fixing the source.